# Runtime resource files with PlayN

Tags: android, mobile, playn

Working on a game that would like to allow users to select different character skins using PlayN (targeting Android as first platform). But these character skins will be made available later on (and due to their size, player may not want to download ALL skins). So rather than create a large bundle with all skins, is there a way for PlayN to access different resource files at runtime? We can setup a server backend for players to browse the latest available skins.

Any help/pointer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Assets.getRemoteImage` to load images remotely.

There is currently no way to cache the downloaded images, which makes this non-optimal for your purposes, but I'm going to add support for caching the downloaded images which should make it work reasonably well if you use texture atlases and don't have a ton of images to download.

If you do need to download dozens or hundreds of images in one fell swoop, then you'll need to write custom per-backend code to handle that (and you'll have to give up using the HTML backend, because it cannot do things like download a zip file and unpack it into local storage).